# For shopping carts, what should be the component, the item or the item options or both?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following data that needs to be turned into a form.

```
var contract = [
  {
    contract_id: 1,
    options: [
      { contract_option_id: 2, contract_id: 1, payment: 'first', price: 100 },
      { contract_option_id: 3, contract_id: 1, payment: 'second', price: 100 },
      { contract_option_id: 4, contract_id: 1, payment: 'full', price: 200 }
    ]
  },
  {
    contract_id: 2,
    options: [
      { contract_option_id: 5, contract_id: 2, payment: 'first', price: 200 },
      { contract_option_id: 6, contract_id: 2, payment: 'second', price: 100 },
      { contract_option_id: 7, contract_id: 2, payment: 'full', price: 300 }
    ]
  },
];
```

I'm basically creating a "shopping cart" to pay contract installments. Each contract has many contract_options which are payment installments. They can either pay the first, second, or entire contract at once depending on what they choose.

So I need to create a form that only allows adding one contract option per item. Here is what I have but I am running into issues with keeping the items independent of eachother and was wondering if i should make a component of the item or the item option?

```
 <table>
   <tr v-for="contract in availableContracts">
     <td>
       <div v-for="option in contract.options">
         <input type="radio" @click="storeInCart(option)" name="item_{{option.contract_id}}" value={{option.price}} >
         {{ option.payment }} ({{ option.price| currency }})
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <button @click="addItem(item)">
      add to cart
    </button>
  </td>

  // remove shows up when item added
  <td><a @click="removeItem(item)">remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

```
new Vue({
el: "#search-results",

data: {
  availableItems: items,
  selectedItem: {},
  cart: cartStorage.fetch()
},

watch: {
  cart: {
    handler: function(cart) {
      cartStorage.save(cart);
    },
    deep: true
  }
},

computed: {
  subTotal: function() {
    var total = 0;
    var cartSize = this.cart.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < cartSize; i++) {
      total += this.cart[i].options[0].price;
    }
    return (total / 100).toFixed(2);
  }
},

methods: {
  addItem: function() {
    this.cart.push(this.selectedItem);
  },

  removeItem: function(item) {
    this.cart.splice(this.cart.indexOf(item), 1);
  },

  storeInCart: function(option) {
    this.selectedContract = {
      contract_id: option.contract_id,
      options: [option]
    };
  }
}
});
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you asking for advice on whether or not you should create each item into a component?

Comment: @m_callens: Yes whether an item should be a component, or an item_option ( the radio button) should be a component, or both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components don't by themselves make this kind of data management easier. They are more about isolation and reuse. Here's what I would suggest.

```
storeInCart: function(option) {
    this.selectedContracts[option.contract_id] = {
      contract_id: option.contract_id,
      options: [option]
    };
}
```

I.e. store the contracts in an object indexed by the contract_id.